# How do I search for files with the same name in two different directories?

Tags: linux, bash

I want to list the files that exists in both directory A and B,

so that both

```
A/file_name

B/file_name
```

exist.

How to do that?

Comment: Look at [this][1] question


  [1]: http://serverfault.com/questions/39534/best-way-to-compare-diff-a-full-directory-structure

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$ comm -12 <(ls A) <(ls B)
```